# How to set div value

Tags: jquery

How do I set the value/text of a `div`?

```
<div id="numberOf"></div>

$("#btn").click(function (event) {
  $.getJSON('http://host/myServiceImpl.svc/GetCount?method=?',
    { id '1' },
    function (data) {
      alert(data);
      $("#numberOf").val = data;
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Text: http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
$("#numberOf").text(data);
```

Html: http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$("#numberOf").html(data);
```

Answer (score 14):

- http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+text+div
- http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+do+i+set+the+value/text+of+a+div%3F

^ Google gives you everything you need. I would suggest googling before asking.

So to answer, you'd want

```
$('#numberOf').text(data)
```

or

```
$('#numberOf').html(data)
```

Comment: second case should be `.html(data)`

Answer (score 3):

or

```
$('#numberOf').html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the text property...

```
$("#btn").click(function (event) {
                $.getJSON('http://host/myServiceImpl.svc/GetCount?method=?', { id '1' },
                function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#numberOf").text(data);

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

if your value is a pure text (like 'test') you could use the text() method as well. like this:

```
 $('#numberOf').text(data); Or $('#numberOf').html(data);
```

> Both are working fine.